# Close BufferedStream without TcpClient disconnect?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, bufferedstream

I am trying to send image via TcpClient and BufferedStream. The problem is that i cant send the data without disconnecting the TcpClient.

Send data:

```
while ((bytesread = bufferedinput.Read(buffer, 0, sizeBuffer)) > 0)
            {
                //Sending data
                bufferedoutput.Write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
            }
```

Receive data:

```
while ((bytesread = bufferedinput.Read(buffer, 0, buffsize)) > 0)
                {
                    bufferedoutput.Write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
                }
```

where :

```
NetworkStream serverStream = client.GetStream();
```

and `BufferedStream bufferedoutput = new BufferedStream(serverStream);`

The problem is that i must cast `bufferedoutput.Close();` in the client side to get the data received by the server, but this disconnects my client, which is a problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evident that by closing NetworkStream object associated with a TcpClient object, disconnects the client. Since TCP is a stream based protocol, you can do only one of two thing, either 1.] use networkstream.readtimeout to disconnect if no data is available till the readtimeout, OR 2.] devise a protocol to tell the receiver about the length of data, sender is willing to send, and read only that length of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just `bufferedoutput.Flush()` instead?

Comment: Yes... When i debug the program i see that the server side code stops the "while" loop after bufferedoutput.Close(); casted in the client side